# Need to create a .doc file with list of items using Aspose

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I have been working on legacy application where i am using Aspose.Words.jdk15.jar to print the .doc file.  I have a requirement where i am getting list of value then we have to loop & print it in the doc file.

And that value we are replacing in doc using range.replace() method . This doc already exists in my workspace where we have mapped the value like this

Component Name:$COMPONENT_NAME
Billing Effective Date:$EFFECTIVE_DATE
Billing End Date:$END_DATE

and the code which i have written to replace the value of doc. So, my requirement is I need this value multiple times in my doc as per size of list.

for(int i=0;i<details.size();i++)
{

doc.getRange().replace("$COMPONENT_NAME" , checkNull(details.get(i).getComponentName()) + “,”, false, false);
doc.getRange().replace("$EFFECTIVE_DATE" , checkNull(details.get(i).getBillEffectiveDate()) + “,”, false, false);
doc.getRange().replace("$END_DATE" , checkNull(details.get(i).getBillEndDate()) + “,”, false, false);
}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you need is using mail Merge feature.
https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/about-mail-merge/
But in this case you need to replace your placeholders with mergefields in your template.
If you cannot change the template, you can clone the the document for each item in your list, replace values in the cloned document and them merge documents together to get the final result. Code will look like the following:

```java
// Open template
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.doc");

// Create document where result will be stored to.
// Simply clone the original template without children,
// In this case styles of the original document will be kept.
Document result = (Document)doc.deepClone(false);

for(int i=0; i<details.length; i++)
{
    Document component = doc.deepClone();

    component.getRange().replace("$COMPONENT_NAME", details[i].getComponentName());
    component.getRange().replace("$EFFECTIVE_DATE", details[i].getBillEffectiveDate().toString());
    component.getRange().replace("$END_DATE", details[i].getBillEndDate().toString());

    // Append the result to the final document.
    result.appendDocument(component, ImportFormatMode.USE_DESTINATION_STYLES);
}

result.save("C:\\Temp\\out.doc");
```

But I would preferer Mail Merge approach.

Comment: Thanks Alexey...i will try this approach

Comment: But the problem is I can't change the template & i have to use same template.
So in this case i have to clone the document & merge it . How can i merge both the document?

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Noskov , Here my requirement is little different . In the same doc we have another data , that we can't repeat & that should appear only one time in doc.

But few field we have to repeat as we are getting list of fields after DB call.

Comment: @SumitRanjan The technique is the same, but in your case you clone only required part of your template. It is difficult to provide you exact code without your template. As I mentioned earlier it would be much easier and correct to use Mail Merge with Regions feature to achieve what you need.

Comment: Address

First Name:$FN
Last Name:$LN
Phone Number:$PHN_NBR


Charges

Component Name:$COMPONENT_NAME  
Effective Date:$EFFECTIVE_DATE              End Date:$END_DATE
Rate:$RATE                                 Currency: $CURRENCY

In my template , i have these fields where Address will be only one time & Charges will be multiple time. It would be very nice if you can give me any code example for this.

Comment: @SumitRanjan As i mentioned earlier it is difficult/impossible to create the code without template. It is required to know nodes structure of your template, not simply text.